# How to avoid full capitalization font in Deedy Resume?

Tags: templates, capitalization, cv, deedy-resume

I am using Deedy Resume style and I want to avoid full-capitalized words in the titles and subtitles. How can I do it?

I am quite new to latex.

Comment: Welcome, Send your MWE.

Comment: Thanks! by MWE you mean the package that I am using?

Comment: `\documentclass[]{deedy-resume-openfont}`

`\section{Objective:}`

`\descript{Interested in Machine Learning, Deep Learning, and NLP`

Comment: Not tested, but editing  `deedy-resume-openfont.cls` to remove the `\uppercase` commands should work.

Answer (score 1):

As @Fran answered. it will be solved by removing \uppercase from deedy-resume-openfont.cls.

```
% Subeadings command
\titleformat{\subsection}{\color{subheadings}
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Bol}\fontsize{12pt}      {12pt}\selectfont\bfseries\uppercase}{}{0em}{}
```

Answer (score 1):

Customizing a template is like changing the melody while singing karaoke. It is a pointless endeavour.

Nevertheless, the simplest but hackiest way to avoud uppercasing would be to add the following to the preamble. No change of the class needed.

```
 \renewcommand{\uppercase}{}
```

If anybody should be interested in the impact of the template [Deedy confusion](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion/blob/master/exampleDeedyResume.md)